# LocationListener stopped to receive the location updates

Tags: android, android-location

I use this code in onResume:

```
final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10 * 1000, 10, this);
        } else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10 * 1000, 10, this);
        }
```

and implemented the LocationListener in Activity. As I see in the debugger, GPS_PROVIDER is enabled. I also see GPS icon when app is working. GPS is enabled in settings. Both the permissons are set. But onLocationChanged is never called. This code worked fine few weeks earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You set updates with minimal time 10 seconds and minimal distance 10 meters. Check that you reach these minimal conditions. Tryu to set all conditions to 0 and check again.

Also, check that GPS updates worked at all - for example, using maps application. If you device used GPS in "cold" start - you can not receive updates 10-20 minutes or more.

Comment: Google Maps works fine. I tried to set 0, and tried to wait about 1/2 hour — the same result.

Comment: Google Maps works fine at all or really updates your location (your position marker on map)?

Comment: Shows my location in building with ~10 meters accuracy

Comment: I'm really confused. It looks like worked solution. Can you test this code on another device?

Comment: doesn't work on Nexus S & Galaxy Note 10.1. BTW, the google map in this application works fine and retrieves location fast.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you

1. Use `Log.d(...)` to check both `locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` and `locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)`
2. Also use `Log.d(...)` to capture all calls to `onProviderDisabled(...)`, `onProviderEnabled(...)` and `onStatusChanged(...)`.

I'd expect that the resulting output will allow you to solve your problem.

Comment: 1. Already checked with debugger, GPS is enabled and <locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER> executed

Comment: But what about calls to `onProviderDisabled(...)`, `onProviderEnabled(...)` and `onStatusChanged(...)`?  Are you saying that none of them get called??

Comment: Checked this with Log.i — nothing happens.